# Retrofit2 Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: php, android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to pass an arraylist to php to do some operations. when i tested with postman i got the following resoponse..

**{"correct_answers":"2","total_question":"5","message":"Great!. You need to score at least 60% of marks to move next level..","message_percentage":"40","saved_message":"success"}**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TODLE.png)

But when I try to send the request i am getting this error..

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $**

this is my api interface

@POST("questions.php")

```
@FormUrlEncoded

Call<QuestionResult> correctQuestionData(@Field("tag") String tag, @Field("str_question_answer[]") ArrayList<QuestionAnswers> str_question_answer,
                                         @Field("student_id")  String student_id, @Field("level") String level);
```

Comment: Please show "QuestionResult" class. I think you made mistake in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that Gson expecting an **object**, but is receiving a **String**, this is because the **format** of the JSON probably is wrong. The JSON has to start with

```
{
```

Please, review the JSON format.

**EDIT:**
Review the parameters of your query, I think that you are sending others parameters instead of what you are putting in postman and the server responding with a String instead of a JSON

Comment: {"correct_answers":"2","total_question":"5","message":"Great!. You need to score at least 60% of marks to move next level..","message_percentage":"40","saved_message":"success"}

this is the format I received when I tested it with postman.

Comment: echo json_encode([
            "correct_answers" => count($correct_answers)."",
            "total_question" => $total_question."",
            "message" => $results["message"],
            "message_percentage" => $percentage."",
            "message"=> $results["message"],
            "saved_message" =>$results["saved_message"]
        ]);


This is what i have defined in the php code

Comment: Try to copy and paste the result from the browser when you fetch the data or put a break point into the funciont "onFailure" in reotrofit2 to kwnow the answer. May be you are sending a wrong paremeter and is not the same answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you made mistake in QuestionResult class. It's format should be like

```
public class QuestionResult{

public String correct_answers;
public String total_question;
public String message;  
public String message_percentage;
public String saved_message;
```

}